# WP_query repeater "NOT LIKE" dosen't working

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater

I have very annoying problem with WP_query and repeater . I try display something if $_GET is not equal to value in my DB. But when compare => NOT LIKE it now working correctly. 
Here is my code:

```
function wyszukiwanie_trasy()
{


    echo '<form action="" method="get">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="od" placeholder="Stacja początkowa">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="do" placeholder="Stacja końcowa">';
    echo '<input type="date" name="data">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Wyszukaj">';
    echo '</form>';
    $loop = new WP_Query(array('meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(

            'key' => 'date_%_daty_wykluczone',
            'value'   => str_replace("-","",$_GET['data'],$i),
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'),

        ),
        array(

            'value'   => $_GET['od'],

        ),
        array(
            'value'   => $_GET['do'],

    ),'post_type' => 'trasy', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        $id = get_the_ID();


        if($_GET['od'] && $_GET['do'] && $_GET['data'] && $_GET['od']!=$_GET['do'])
        {
            if( have_rows('location') ):

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('location') ) : the_row();

                    // display a sub field value
                    ?>
                    <span style="font-weight: bold"><?php the_sub_field('lokacja');?></span>
                    <?php
                    echo ' ';
                endwhile;

                echo '<br />';
            else :

                echo 'Brak połączeń';

            endif;

        }
        echo $loop->request;

endwhile; wp_reset_query();

    }
```

**Here is my SQL request:**

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'date_%_daty_wykluczone' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%20180715%' ) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'trasy' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Imo is is something wrong with 'key' => 'date_%_daty_wykluczone', in my DB that meta keys looks like: date_0_daty_wykluczone date_1_daty_wykluczone, cause when i change this 'key' => 'date_%_daty_wykluczone', to 'key' => 'date_1_daty_wykluczone', 'NOT LIKE' works correctly

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" - what is the result of the query and what did you expect? Is there any valid data in the database which might be selected by this query?

Comment: I got some date type values in my DB.For example '20180715'. I want get all location where $_GET['data'] is not equal to date types values in my DB. Atm if compare => 'NOT LIKE' it shows all post where $_GET['od'] and $_GET['do'] are equal to values in my DB.

Comment: Your basic logic is flawed here already. If you have a post with two such meta entries, `date_0_daty_wykluczone = 20180715` and `date_1_daty_wykluczone = 20280101`, then of course you will still get that post returned with that kind of NOT LIKE filtering - because there _is_ a record with a matching key and a date that is _not_ the one you are trying to filter out.

Comment: So in that case compare=> 'LIKE' should only works where is a record with matching key. In my case 'LIKE' works correctly with meta key = 'date_%_daty_wykluczone'

Answer (score 0):

Try this code structure,

Using the "Relation" for the Meta Query, you can select multiple Meta Keys. You can change the "Compare" to any of the operations available for that function. (From the Codex) compare (string) - Operator to test. Possible values are '=', '!=', '>', '>=', '<', '<=', 'LIKE', 'NOT LIKE', 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'BETWEEN', 'NOT BETWEEN', 'EXISTS' and 'NOT EXISTS'. Default value is '='.

```html
// WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
            'post_type'          => 'your-post-type',
                'meta_query'          => array(
                'relation' => 'AND', 
             array(
                 'key'       => 'color',
                 'value'     => 'Red',
                 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                    ),

             array(
                 'key' => 'color',
                 'value' => 'Plain',
                 'compare' => 'Like'
                    ),
                 ), 
             );

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        // do something
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}

// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Meta_query compare operator explanation**

The first several work about like you would expect:

```html
=   equals
!=  does not equal
>   greater than
>=  greater than or equal to
<   less than
<=  less than or equal to
```

**LIKE** and **NOT LIKE** are SQL operators that let you add in wild-card symbols, so you could have a meta query that looks like this:

```html
array( 
    'key' => 'name', 
    'value' => 'Pat', 
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
)
```

This would return all posts where the meta value "name" has the string "Pat". In this case, "Pat" "Patricia" and "Patrick" would all be returned back to you. There's a non-WordPress tutorial explanation [here](http://www.htmlite.com/mysql011.php)

Comment: Unfortunately in my case only works  '=', ''LIKE', 'IN' and 'EXISTS' . Others "symbols" show me incorrectly result :(

Comment: others ''symbols' means which symbols are not working??

Comment: != , < , > , <= , >= , BETWEEN , NOT BETWEEN , NOT LIKE , NOT IN , NOT EXIST

Comment: Imo is is something wrong with `'key' => 'date_%_daty_wykluczone',` in my DB that meta keys looks like:
date_0_daty_wykluczone
date_1_daty_wykluczone, cause when i change this `'key' => 'date_%_daty_wykluczone',` to `'key' => 'date_1_daty_wykluczone',` NOT like works correctly

Comment: I fix it in other way but your comment helps me with that :) So thank you for your help :)

Comment: Welcome... Hope you got your proper solution. If my comments are useful then Give me points of that :)